# What's this javascript structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some confusion between several JS structures, one of them is this one:
http://pastebin.com/uZD9dfCH

What's that? Is that a class? A function? An extension to jquery?

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between all those JS structures.

Any help will be appreciated :D

Comment: Literally, that is a link to pastebin.com, it isn't a javascript structure. If you are refering to the code at the page targeted by that link, it is a jQuery document ready handler. The code really should be posted directly in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a shortcut for `$( document ).ready( function () { /* Code here */ } )`